# Как поставить библиотеку С++ без или с Cmake

Tags: c++, curl, cmake

Я нашел [оболочку для curl](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr)  и пытаюсь ее "собрать"
Что я сделал:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr.git

git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Я работаю с visual studio 2017. Создал обычное консольное приложение (не СMake).

Я не понимаю алгоритм, что я должен сделать дальше чтобы
 `#include <cpr/cpr.h>`  - не светилась красным.

Я пробовал создать `CMakeLists.txt` и прописать там данные строки, но ничего не получилось.

> Next, add this subdirectory to your `CMakeLists.txt` before declaring
>   any targets that might use it:

```
add_subdirectory(cpr)
```

> This will produce two important CMake variables, `CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS`
>   and `CPR_LIBRARIES`, which you'll use in the typical way:

```
include_directories(${CPR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(your_target_name ${CPR_LIBRARIES})
```

Я получаю сообщение :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (project):
  Running
   'C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe' '--version'

  failed with:

   Версия "%1" не совместима с версией Windows, работающей на этом компьютере. Проверьте сведения о системе, чтобы узнать, какая версия программы x86 (32-разрядная) или x64 (64-разрядная) вам нужна, и получите ее у поставщика программного обеспечения.
```

Comment: Все как обычно, в настройках компилятора прописываете пути к заголовочным файлам библиотеки и препроцессорные директивы для ее контроля, в настройках линкера прописываете пути к экспортным или статическим библиотекам этой библиотеки и указываете их имена. с CMAKE то же самое делается путем проброса этих значений через систему магических макросов.

Comment: @VTT, вы убедили меня скачать  СMake.

Comment: Все проще, вам надо скачать 32 бит версию Cmake :) то что вы скачали у вас не запускается вообще

Comment: @NewView Судя по вопросу, ОП "пробовал создать CMakeLists.txt" когда у него вообще не было cmake.

Comment: С CMake все в порядке, это ninja не той архитектуры. Но раз уж вы в студии работаете, то нужно генерировать проект студии, а ninja-файлы.

Comment: @arrowd,  я скачал СMake, создал проект СMake проект в студии, в внешнем(тот что первый в папке проекта) Cmake Lists.txt прописал все строки для него , потом в CMake  его собрал,  предварительно иницилизировал в папке "студийного" проекта Cmake репозиторий и скачал командами для Git папку cpr. И собрал Cmake и собралось, даже скомпилировалось, но не запскается